# How do you use try except for library specific errors?

Tags: python, pygame, try-catch, except

I am initializing a gamepad in my program, but if the gamepad isn't connected it will return the error:

```
pygame.error: Invalid joystick device number
```

My current code is this:

```
try:
    init_controller()
except pygame.error:
    use_keyboard = True
```

How would I format the except clause to except only this pygame error and not all pygame errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Direct answer to your question**: Since the exceptions are all the same type, then your options are limited to simply checking the exception message and then re-raise the exception if it's not a match. Or since you're only wrapping that function with try/except, it's safe to assume it's a joystick error and not something else. Buuuuut.....

**The real answer to your question**: You can check to see how many joysticks are present using `pygame.joystick.get_count()`. If it's 0, don't call the function.